# Windows 8 WPF Apps

Tags: wpf, windows, windows-8, windows-runtime

Anyone have any resources for getting started developing WPF apps on Windows 8? I have been to MSDN and Googled alot, but since Windows 8 is still in preview, there's not alot out there as far as development resources.

Thanks

Comment: Are you just starting out with WPF in general?  If so, any of the existing resources is a good enough start.  If you are looking to leverage newer Windows 8 features only, then that's another story.  :)  Good luck!

Answer (score 6):

WPF apps for Windows 8/.NET 4.5 are nearly the same as WPF apps for Windows 7/.NET 4

If this is what you want, ignore Windows 8 and focus on WPF for now and pick Windows 8/.NET 4.5 up when .NET 4.5 is released.

Metro apps for Windows 8 are very different and are more similar to Windows Phone 7 and Silverlight.

To learn Metro apps you can use [the Developer Preview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/br229516.aspx) and [online SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/).

Comment: Good news is that there's now a Blend Preview for WPF 4.5 - http://blendinsider.com/technical/announcing-blend-sketchflow-preview-for-visual-studio-2012-2012-08-15/